# Duplicate operation error when Generating classes from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I tried to generate classes from a WSDL file by this command line:

```
java -cp ".\*" org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java Tadm.wsdl
```

but I have got this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate operation with name=myOperation, found in portType '{http://www.....}ServiceSoap'.
    at com.ibm.wsdl.PortTypeImpl.getOperation(PortTypeImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populateBindings(SymbolTable.java:2515)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know that the latest version of WSDL specification doesn't support overloaded operation, so is there a technology or feature support overloaded operation to generate the classes from WSDL file **without** any operation renaming or modifications?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270765/generating-classes-from-wsdl-duplicate-operation-with-name-error

Comment: thank you, but the related said you have to change the name of operation but I can't do that and thank you for your edits @Petter Friberg